# Convert binary to IP address using MySQL bitwise operation

Tags: php, mysql, ip, bitwise-operators

**Question:** Is it possible to convert a binary (`varbinary(16)`) into a IPv4 & IPv6 address using a MySQL bitwise operation in a `SELECT` query? If so, how?

I know there is a MySQL `INET6_NTOA()` function but that's only available for MySQL 5.6.3+. And I know PHP has the `inet_ntop()` function but I rather use a bitwise operation if possible.

**PHP:**

```
/**
 * createQueryParam
 *
 * Determines what MySQL function should be used based on MySQL version.
 *
 * @param   $ip                     The visitor's IP address or ip field in database table.
 * @access  public
 * @return  string
 */
public function createQueryParam($ip, $select_query=FALSE)
{
    # Set the Database instance to a variable.
    $db=DB::get_instance();
    # Get the database client version.
    $client_version=$db->client_version;

    # If the client version is 5.6.3+ use INET6_ATON.
    if($client_version>=50603)
    {
        # If this is not for a select query.
        if($select_query===FALSE)
        {
            return " INET6_ATON('".$ip."')";
        }
        # This is for a select query.
        return ' INET6_NTOA(`'.$ip.'`)';
    }
    # Else we assume PHP has IPv6 support and use PHP's inet_pton() to convert the IP to a binary.
    else
    {
        # If this is not for a select query.
        if($select_query===FALSE)
        {
            # If IPv4 then use MySQL function.
            if($this->getIPVersion()==4)
            {
                return " INET_ATON('".$ip."')";
            }
            else
            {
                # Supports IPv4 & IPv6 (if PHP has IPv6 supprot enabled).
                return inet_pton($ip);
            }
        }
        # NOTE: How to handle select queries for IPv6 if MySQL version is less then 5.6.3?
        # Can a MySQL bitwise operation be used here?
        # IPv4 Only.
        //return ' INET_NTOA(`'.$ip.'`)';
        # For IPv6 I could use PHP's inet_ntop() but we can't return it here.
    }
} #=== End -- createQueryParam
```